# Is it possible to get the whole http request via chrome.downloads API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When user download a file, Is it possible to catch the whole chrome request via [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) API?

There are the events [onDeterminingFilename](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename) and [onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onCreated) where I can extract the following keys and values (if I download some dummy pdf from the url `http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf`)

```
bytesReceived :0
canResume:false
danger:safe
exists:true
fileSize: 3028
filename:sample.pdf
finalUrl: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
id:6787
incognito:false
mime:application/pdf
paused: false
referrer: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
startTime:2020-07-28T12:10:03.087Z
state:in_progress
totalBytes: 3028
url :http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
```

Is it possible the get the whole request via the api? I mean all headers, coockies etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API for that purpose.